# Any way to optimize the following SQL query (it uses looping and finally an update)?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

```
 `populateSS`(IN mm_id VARCHAR(255), IN orig_mm_id VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

    -- The 3 columns from the row which will be populated from a select and a conditional defaulted to false

    DECLARE ss_value varchar(255);
    DECLARE item_s varchar(255);
    DECLARE part varchar(255);
    declare done BOOLEAN default false;
    
    SELECT SS_Item_Number FROM mm_book WHERE `Code`=mm_id INTO ss_value;
    SELECT Item_Status FROM mm_book WHERE `Code`=mm_id INTO item_s;
    SELECT `Code` FROM mm_book WHERE `Code`=mm_id INTO part;

    WHILE done != true DO
        CASE item_s
            WHEN  'SS' THEN
                -- CALL UpdateSSColumn(ss_value,orig_mm_id);
                SELECT Item_Status FROM mm_book WHERE `Code`=ss_value INTO item_s;
                SELECT `Code` FROM mm_book WHERE `Code`=ss_value INTO part;
                SELECT IFNULL(SS_Item_Number,'default') FROM mm_book WHERE `Code`=ss_value INTO ss_value;
            ELSE
                SET done = true;
                UPDATE parts_sub SET ss_part_num = part WHERE part_no = orig_mm_id COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
        END CASE;
    END WHILE;
END
```

I'm not fully sure how I can optimize this query I originally wrote it using recursion and switched to a while loop which shaved off 2 seconds or so but still 5 seconds for this query is too long. Also each column used in the query is indexed.

Comment: SELECT INTO allows to select more than one column and put their values into according amount of variables. No reason to select into variables and then use them in UPDATE - use single multiple-table UPDATE.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what the query is doing. I see something about books and numbers, but that's about it. It is normal to give the structure of the database, and explain the query, in questions like this.

Comment: this looks like it could be done in a single update query. Post a [mre] to explain what you exactly expect. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @nbk I think the solution with a single UPDATE will require a recursive CTE because of the way the loop sets `ss_value` based on the previous iteration until it gets to `item_s != 'SS'`

Comment: @Barmar that is why i said looks like, but he goes linear through a table and stops when a cöumn is not equal to SS, that makes no sense as table and rsult sets are unsorted so a [mre should help clear things up

Comment: @nbk It looks like a hierarchical relationship, he's following the child->parent links.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why have one query per variable? You can replace the blocks of three queries by a single one:

```
SELECT ss_item_number, item_status, code
FROM mm_book
WHERE code = mm_id 
INTO ss_value, item_s, part;
```

and

```
SELECT IFNULL(ss_item_number, 'default'), item_status, code
FROM mm_book
WHERE code = ss_value
INTO ss_value, item_s, part;
```

The optimal index for this is a covering index (i.e. it contains all columns mentioned in the query) that starts with the code:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON mm_book (code, ss_item_number, item_status);
```

Comment: the algorithm makes no sense at all, and so reducing the select to one will do not much

Comment: @nbk: What makes you say so?  To me it looks like a hierarchical table and we move from level to level until we reach the end.